# Odoo15 - error when i try to install a module

Tags: odoo-15

I am trying to create a form structure for save information a two tables, but i am get a error. Can anyone help me
I search in the odoo15 documentation but its don't help me too much.
I think the error is not inside the menu item but in other lines code.

**This is my model**

```
from odoo import models, fields


class dga_doc(models.Model):
    _name = "dnre.dga_doc"
    _auto = False
    _description = "DNRE - Recursos Humanos"

    nc = fields.Integer(string="Nº contribuente", required=True)
    dc = fields.Char(string="Designação contribuente", required=True)
    ca = fields.Integer(string="CA")
    da = fields.Char(string="DA")
    mr = fields.Date(string="MR")
    tc = fields.Integer(string="TC")
    r = fields.Char(string="Regime")
    dga = fields.One2many('dnre.dga', 'dga_id', string="DGA Lines", readonly="True")

class dga(models.Model):
    _name = "dnre.dga"
    _description = "DGA Funcionarios"

    dga_id = fields.Many2one('dnre.dga_doc', string="dga", readonly="True")
    nums = fields.Integer(string="Nº segurado", required=True)
    ns = fields.Char(string="Nome segurado", required=True)
    cp = fields.Char(string="CP")
    pc = fields.Char(string="P/C")
    ndt = fields.Integer(string="Nº DT")
    sl = fields.Integer(string="SL")
    cs = fields.Char(string="CS")
    cf = fields.Integer(string="CF")
    cep = fields.Integer(string="CEP")
```

**This is my view**

```
<odoo>
  <data>
    <!-- Top menu item -->
    <menuitem name="DNRE" id="dnre.menu_root"/>

    <!-- menu categories -->
    <menuitem name="FOS" id="dnre.menu_1" parent="dnre.menu_root"/>

    <!-- actions -->
    <menuitem name="DGA" id="dnre.menu_1_list" parent="dnre.menu_1" action="dnre.action_dga"/>
    <menuitem name="DGCI" id="dnre.menu_2_list" parent="dnre.menu_1" action="dnre.action_dgci"/>

    <!-- actions opening views on models -->
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="dnre.action_dga">
      <field name="name">Folha de Orçamento Salarial</field>
      <field name="res_model">dnre.dgci_doc</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree, form</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="dnre.action_dgci">
      <field name="name">Folha de Orçamento Salarial</field>
      <field name="res_model">dnre.dga_doc</field>
      <field name="view_mode">tree, form</field>
    </record>

    <!-- server action to the one above -->
    <record model="ir.actions.server" id="dnre.action_server">
      <field name="name">dnre server</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_dnre_dga_doc"/>
      <field name="state">code</field>
      <field name="code">
        action = {
          "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
          "view_mode": "tree, form",
          "res_model": model._name,
        }
      </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="dnre.list_dga">
      <field name="name">dnre dga list</field>
      <field name="model">dnre.dga_doc</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
          <group string="Informação do documento">
            <group colspan="4" col="6">
              <field name="nc"/>
              <field name="dc"/>
              <field name="ca"/>
              <field name="da"/>
              <field name="mr"/>
              <field name="tc"/>
              <field name="r"/>
            </group>
          </group>
          <notebook>
            <page string="Funcionários DGA">
              <field name="dga">
                <tree>
                  <field name="nums"/>
                  <field name="ns"/>
                  <field name="cp"/>
                  <field name="pc"/>
                  <field name="ndt"/>
                  <field name="sl"/>
                  <field name="cs"/>
                  <field name="cf"/>
                  <field name="cep"/>
                </tree>
              </field>
            </page>
          </notebook>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

**This is the error that i am having**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ruben/Documents/MyLab/DNRE/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 694, in _handle_exception
    return super()._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/ruben/Documents/MyLab/DNRE/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 324, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /home/ruben/Documents/MyLab/DNRE/dnre-addons/dnre/views/dga.xml:10, somewhere inside
<menuitem name="DGA" id="dnre.menu_1_list" parent="dnre.menu_1" action="dnre.action_dga"/>
```

Comment: try moving the actions before to the menu items

Answer (score 0):

1st: stop using `dnre.xxxx` prefix for define a record, you could use `dnre_xxxx` definition. When you define a record with `dnre.xxxx` Odoo with try to find the view `xxxx` for the `dnre` module and override it, this is how external ids works in Odoo. Don't mess with that or you will get more problems than now.

2nd: be aware where you define a view, Odoo respects your definitions from the top to the bottom. Op1: if you are working in one file you don't need externals ids, you sould define your view on top and use then on the bottom. Op2: working with more files, if you need to call some views defined in the file A from the file B you need to use externals ids, using this pattern `module_name.view_id`, in this case in `__manfiest__` file you should define file A first an then file B.

If it is Op1. you could use this pattern of definitions:

1. tree, form, kamban, search, pivots, graph view(the order don't matters).
2. actions.
3. Menus

I hope this answer can help you.